# AspectJ load time weaving isn't work

Tags: java, spring, maven, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I want to configure my spring project to work with AspectJ load time weaving. 
I've done following:

1. added a `<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>` in my application contex
2. added aspectj in cache
3. added lines in my pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
       <version>${springframework.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
       <version>${springframework.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
       <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
       <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ...........

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <goals>
                   <project>test</project>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <detail>true</detail>
                   <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                   <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-instrument-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar"</argLine>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

I have a test, and it fails.

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.FORM_TEMPLATE)
public int getRandomInt(){
    return new Random().nextInt();
}

@Test
public void test(){
    int i = getRandomInt();
    assertEquals(i, getRandomInt());
}
```

Can somebody explain why it fails? It obvious that load time weaving isn't work.

Comment: Your `@Cacheable` is on a non spring managed bean and as such not applicable to loadtimeweavig. It will only work for spring managed beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, M. Deinum! Your comment is very useful! 
I've rewrited my test as follows

DaoObject

```
interface DaoObject {
    int getCachedNumber();
}
```

DaoObjectImpl

```
@Repository
public class DaoObjectImpl implements DaoObject {
    @Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.FORM_TEMPLATE)
    public int getRandomInt(){
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCachedNumber() {
        return getRandomInt();
    }
}
```

And my test now looks like

```
@Test
public void cacheTest(){
    assertEquals(daoObject.getCachedNumber(), daoObject.getCachedNumber());
}
```

All fine. Thanks!

Comment: Testing the caching by looking at Random values is a great idea!